# How can I present histogram per cluster number in one plot

Tags: r, cluster-computing, histogram

I use k-means analysis and bind the cluster number (km$cluster) to my original data frame.
I would like to present histogram per cluster number in one plot (each km$cluster contains at least 2000 observations). Is it possible?How can i do it?Many thanks,Ron

```
dd <- "UserID MoneyAmount DaysReg km$cluster \n 1 5 6 1.4 1 \n 2 4 9 1.4 1 \n 3 6 7 1.3 1 \n 4 7 30 9.4 2" 
Data <- read.table(text=dd, header = TRUE) 
sessionInfo() 
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit) 
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1 flexclust_1.3-4 modeltools_0.2-21 lattice_0.20-23 RODBC_1.3-10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `MoneyAmount` is your value of interest. The following code plots a histogram of `MoneyAmount` for each cluster.

```
require(ggplot2)
qplot(data=Data,x=MoneyAmount,facets=km.cluster ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ziggystar, I tried your solution here:
qplot(data=NewRusSep13,x=km$cluster,facets=cluster ~ .)
But i got this error massage so i guess I'm doing somthing wrong..
Error in layout_base(data, rows, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
--Thanks,Ron

Comment: @user1024441 If you provide a reproducible example in your question, I can give you the exact code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: UserID km$number DaysFromReg MoneyAmount
391068166810 2 320 70
391068166811 1 12 40
391068166812 1 10 38

Comment: @user1024441 You should read the link in my comment. In particular if you are going to ask more R questions. From your last comment I can tell you didn't read it.

Comment: I'm a noob to Stackoverfolw.com  so i thought the link is internal issue - I'll look it right now.

Comment: For this question, some sample data (in the form of runnable R-code, e.g. produced with `dput`) might be enough. For further questions you should also give code you have tried to achieve what you want and say why it didn't work.

Comment: dd <-     "UserID MoneyAmount       DaysReg      km$cluster
+ 1          5         6             1.4         1  
+ 2          4         9             1.4         1 
+ 3          6         7             1.3         1  
+ 4          7         30            9.4         2"
Data <- read.table(text=dd, header = TRUE)

sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
  
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1   flexclust_1.3-4   modeltools_0.2-21 lattice_0.20-23   RODBC_1.3-10

Comment: @user1024441 Your pasted code didn't work. I fixed it and added it to your question.